# Checking folder and subfolders for file name and retrieving spreadsheet url

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm new to google api, I've worked with other coding languages (matlab mainly) but am struggling with learning all the capabilities and syntax for google api. I have a large google drive folder that has a lot of docs for the sports team I coach. The file names remain mostly the same from year to year (the only change is the year in the title). Within these docs, they link to other docs in the main folder or sub-folders. Is there a way I can make a script that will search my main folder all sub-folders in my drive for a google sheet document name and then once it's found it return the url of that google sheet to either a google doc or a google sheet cell?

For example, my main season folder is called "2024 season", then within that there's folders called "organizational info", "pre-season meeting", etc. one thing i link consistently is our "roster" and pull in data from that google sheet to other google sheets using importrange().

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow - https://stackoverflow.com/tour.
I've answered it but for next time please note that at Stack overflow you are expected to post the code which you've tried and are stuck with a particular issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you want the list of URLs of all Google docs present inside your main folder and it's sub folders.

Here's how you can do it. Create a container bound apps script in Google Sheets and run the function populateGoogleDocsData. It will get the list of title and URLs of all Google Docs in your main folder and it's subfolders, and populate it in Google Sheets.

```
function populateGoogleDocsData() {
  var folderId = "YOUR_FOLDER_ID";
  var googleDocsData = listGoogleDocsInFolder(folderId);
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  // Clear existing data
  sheet.clear();
  
  // Set headers
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 2).setValues([["Name", "URL"]]);
  
  // Populate data
  if (googleDocsData.length > 0) {
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, googleDocsData.length, 2).setValues(googleDocsData);
  }
}


function listGoogleDocsInFolder(folderId) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  var googleDocs = [];
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var name = file.getName();
    var url = file.getUrl();
    googleDocs.push([name, url]);
  }
  
  // Recursively list Google Docs in subfolders
  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var subfolder = subfolders.next();
    var subfolderGoogleDocs = listGoogleDocsInFolder(subfolder.getId());
    googleDocs = googleDocs.concat(subfolderGoogleDocs);
  }
  
  return googleDocs;
}
```